# Adjoint of bounded linear map is isometric isomorphism implies original map is isometric isomorphism?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, dual-spaces

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are normed spaces. Let $T$ be a bounded linear map from $X$ to $Y$. Let $T^*$ be the adjoint map from $Y^{*}$ to $X^{*}$ defined by $T^{*}(y^*) = y^* T$.

A straightforward calculation shows:

**Theorem 1.** If $T$ is an isometric isomorphism from $X$ onto $Y$, then $T^*$ is an isometric isomorphism from $Y^*$ onto $X^*$.

I'm trying to prove the converse.

But the best I can get is the following. (It comes by applying the above theorem with $T^*$ in place of $T$ and using that $T^{**}$ extends $T$ [if $X$ is identified with a subspace of $X^{**}$ in the natural way]).

**Theorem 2.** If $T^*$ is an isometric isomorphism from $Y^*$ onto $X^*$, then $T$ is an isometric isomorphism from $X$ into $Y$ and $T(X)$ is dense in $Y$.

I cannot seem to strengthen the conclusion to $T$ is surjective.

If $X$ is complete, or, more generally, if $T(X)$ is closed in $Y$, then $T$ is surjective.

But what happens if $X$ is not complete or $T(X)$ is not closed?

In the discussion of the following question, the OP claims to be able to prove that $T^{∗}$ being an isomorphism implies $T$ is surjective, but I don't see how:

[$T$ is surjective if and only if the adjoint $T^*$ is an isomorphism (onto its image)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510767/t-is-surjective-if-and-only-if-the-adjoint-t-is-an-isomorphism-onto-its-i)

There are also some Hilbert space examples in the following links, but they don't address what I am asking about:

[$T$ surjective iff $T^*$ injective in infinite-dimensional Hilbert space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269105/t-surjective-iff-t-injective-in-infinite-dimensional-hilbert-space?rq=1)

[Example: operator injective, then the adjoint is NOT surjective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096255/example-operator-injective-then-the-adjoint-is-not-surjective)

Comment: Related: [If the dual spaces are isometrically isomorphic are the spaces isomorphic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/647311)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement does not hold unless you assume both spaces are Banach spaces.  This is because the dual space is the dual space of a normed space is (naturally isomorphic to) the dual of its completion.

Indeed, let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional, not complete normed space, let $\tilde X$ denote its completion, and let $T:X\to \tilde X$ be the canonical inclusion.  Then $T^*$ is an isometric isomorphism, but $T$ is not a surjective isometry.

Comment: This example clearly shows that completeness of $X$ is necessary to get $T$ surjective in Theorem 2. But I am having trouble understanding why $Y$ needs to be complete. I am pretty sure Theorem 2 is true as stated. Suppose we add the hypothesis that $X$ is complete and $Y$ is not complete. Then $T(X)$ will be complete because of the conclusion that $T$ is an isometric isomorphism. Hence $\overline{T(X)} = T(X)$. Combining this with the conclusion that $T(X)$ is dense in $Y$, we get that $Y = \overline{T(X)} = T(X)$. But this will mean that $Y$ is complete. Contradiction. Continued in next...

Comment: So is this saying that when $X$ is complete and $Y$ is not complete, then $T^{*}:Y^{*} \to X^{*}$ cannot be an isometric isomorphism? This is confusing because the duals $Y^{*}$ and $X^*$ cannot detect whether $X$ and $Y$ are complete. What is going on here?

Comment: I don't really know how to answer.  This may help: even though $X^*$ and $Y^*$ can't detect whether or not $X$ and $Y$ are complete, the map $T^*:Y^*\to X^*$ is constructed from the map $T:X\to Y$.

Comment: Yes, I've come to the same understanding. Thanks for your excellent example.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help!